# How to automate kinit process to obtain TGT for Kerberos?

Tags: linux, active-directory, authentication, kerberos

I'm currently writing a puppet module to automate the process of joining RHEL servers to an AD domain, with support for Kerberos.

Currently, I have problems with automatically obtain and cache Kerberos ticket-granting ticket via `kinit`. If this were to be done manually, I would do this:

```
kinit aduser@REALM.COM
```

This prompts for the AD user password, hence there is a problem with automate this.

How can I automate this? I've found some posts mentioning using `kadmin` to create a database with the AD users password in it, but I've had no luck.

Answer (score 22):

Stupid me, you can simply use following command:

```
echo "password" | kinit aduser@REALM
```

Comment: `echo -n "$PASS" | kinit "$USER"` do not output trailing newline

Comment: Or print a poster with your password and hang it out!
Storing your password in plain text is a no-no

Answer (score 21):

While you can just hard-code the password into your automation, the more correct Kerberos way to do this is to create a keytab for the principal and then use that to authenticate.  `kinit` supports authenticating from a keytab using the `-k -t <keytab-path>` options.

The primary advantage of a keytab is that it isolates the credentials in a separate file and can be used directly by various Kerberos software (so you don't have to add code to read a password from a separate file).  It can also be created with standard commands (with an AD KDC, use `ktpass`).  There are some more advantages if you had a Linux KDC, such as easily randomizing keys stored in the keytab rather than using a weaker password.

Comment: Keytab definitely seems to be the way to go. If you generate this in kadmin, make sure to use the `-norandkey` flag in ktadd if you don't want to invalidate the existing password.

Answer (score 2):

According to the man-page you might use:

```
kinit --password-file="~/my.secret" aduser@REALM.COM
```

So you just might provide your password via a file.

Comment: does it work in windows ?

Comment: FYI, `--password-file=` is available with the `kinit` command that comes as a part of Heimdal Kerberos. It's not available with MIT Kerberos' `kinit` command.